# How does PHP Composer find a package by version?

Tags: php, git, version-control, github, composer-php

Let's say my `composer.json` file contains

```
"require": {
    "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "5.0.*"
}
```

Then how does Composer locate SwiftMailer version 5.0.0 or any other 5.0.* version but not 4.9 or 5.1? How is the version matching processed, is it based on info from GitHub or from somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses a JSON API. In Swift's case, `https://packagist.org/packages/swiftmailer/swiftmailer.json` is being parsed.

Matching versions is done per the docs at https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#package-versions.

Comment: So is extra/branch-alias field (https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md) in a package's composer.json the only source of info about the package's version for Composer or there are other such sources